# lodash _.findIndex by multiple values

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

How can i find in array the index by multiple values.
This is because of mysql composite key.
This works with simple key :

```
var recordPos = _.findIndex(myData, function (obj) {
        return obj[pk] == lastInsertedid;
    });
```

but if i need to find ex:

```
pk=["RHID","CD_DOC_ID","SEQ"] 

lastInsertedid=["1","2","3"]
```

I apreciate very much your help

Comment: Like.. return a sorted array instead of a single object?

Comment: How does myData look like?

Comment: Its an array of objects and below one object

Comment: {
  "RHID": "2",
  "CD_DOC_ID": "1",
  "SEQ": "1",
  "NR_DOCUMENTO": "8049654",
  "EMISSOR": "Lisboa 77",
  "DT_EMISSAO": "2008-01-02",
  "DT_VALIDADE": "2018-05-02",
  "NOME_FICHEIRO": "2IMG_0436.JPG"
}

Comment: @Thomas. No, find the index . Kind of " where rhid=1 and cd_doc_id=1 and seq=1 "

Comment: or it works if i put the values in lastInsertedid=["1","2","3"] to pk=["RHID","CD_DOC_ID","SEQ"]  to achive pk={"RHID":"1","CD_DOC_ID":"2","SEQ":"3"} then i can do_.findIndex(myData, pk);

Comment: or it works if i put the values in lastInsertedid=["1","2","3"] to pk=["RHID","CD_DOC_ID","SEQ"]  to achive pk={"RHID":"1","CD_DOC_ID":"2","SEQ":"3"} then i can do_.findIndex(myData, pk); Thanks

Answer (score 2):

solved

```
var pk = {};
_.each(Form.formAttributes.pk.primary, function (k, i) {
    pk[k] = lastInsertedId[i];
});
Form.currentRecord = _.findIndex(Form.myData[Form.arrData], pk);
```